# How to merge N Python dictionaries without overwriting values?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_ds = [
    {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5], 'c': [6, 7]},
    {'a': [4], 'b': [56], 'c': [46]},
    {'a': [92], 'b': [65], 'c': [43]}
]
```

and I want this as output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'b': [4, 5, 56, 65], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43]}
```

Until now ...

I tried

```
d_of_ds = reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.update(d2), list_of_ds)
```

gives: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`

I tried

```
d_of_ds = reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.update(d2) or d1, list_of_ds, {})
```

Overwrites each iteration: `{'a': [92], 'b': [65], 'c': [43]}`

I tried

```
d_of_ds = {k: v for d in list_of_ds for k, v in d.items()}
```

Overwrites each iteration: `{'a': [92], 'b': [65], 'c': [43]}`

Comment: Why are you trying these crazy one liners? Go for a simple loop based solution.

Answer (score 5):

Using `reduce` is not a good idea in this case.Also your lambda function has a wrong logic at all, because you are trying to update the whole of dictionaries together, not their elements see the following :

```
>>> a={'a':[1,2], 'b':[4,5],'c':[6,7]}
>>> a.update({'a':[4], 'b':[56],'c':[46]})
>>> a
{'a': [4], 'c': [46], 'b': [56]}
```

But as a more efficient way you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method :

```
>>> new={}
>>> for d in list_of_ds:
...    for i,j in d.items():
...       new.setdefault(i,[]).extend(j)
... 
>>> new
{'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43], 'b': [4, 5, 56, 65]}
```

Also you can use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for sub in list_of_ds:
...    for i,j in sub.items():
...       d[i].extend(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43], 'b': [4, 5, 56, 65]})
```

Comment: @vaultah You can read the source to find that https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: @vaultah There is no thing wrong with source :) but its not efficient to `Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable` when we could use a linear solution like `defaultdict` or `setdefault`!

Comment: @vaultah Reduce is a bad idea because it's counterintuitive to use on non-associative or side-effecting code and is algorithmically slow if side-effects are avoided. Further, it's slower and less clear than a simple loop.

Answer (score 3):

Not-so-efficient but pretty [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) solution:

```
def f(x, y):
    return {k: x.get(k, []) + y.get(k, []) for k in set(x).union(y)}

from functools import reduce
reduce(f, list_of_ds) # {'b': [4, 5, 56, 65], 'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43]}
```

Not-so-pretty but efficient solution using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(list_of_ds):
    new = defaultdict(list)
    for d in list_of_ds:
        for k, v in d.items():
            new[k].extend(v)
    return new # or dict(new), to obtain a 'dict' object

f(list_of_ds) # {'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'b': [4, 5, 56, 65], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43]}
```

Answer (score 1):

without importing any library

```
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> new_dict
{}
>>> for dct in list_of_ds:
        for key,val in dct.items():
            if key not in new_dict.keys(): new_dict[key] = val
            else: new_dict[key].extend(val)


>>> new_dict
{'a': [1, 2, 4, 92], 'c': [6, 7, 46, 43], 'b': [4, 5, 56, 65]}
```